# What features and other properties are needed to connect to SQL using PowerShell from a server?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-server-2016

I've been running the same script on our current server (2008 R2) for a while now, with no issues.

```
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=11.11.111.11;Database=TESTON;User ID=ADMINID;Password=THEREISNOTRY"
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select * from Projects"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$SqlConnection.Close()
foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
    Write-Host "the column data of the row"
}
```

We are migrating this and other code to a new server (2016), and the same commands produce the following error:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify 
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

I can reach the same data server from the new one, so the problem seems to be the powershell trying to connect. The PowerShell versions are slightly different

Good Server: 5.1.14409.1018
Bad Server: 5.1.14393.3053

I've been unable to get the bad server to update to the same exact version, and I've tried changing the Integrated Security around. Also, I checked which server features where enabled, and the bad server was missing some, but I added those to match up (as best it could).

What are some things, or what is the thing that I could check/change to get this to connect? Is there a simple fix of changing a "config" file somewhere that would just need the new IPs added?

Comment: Does the new server allow remote connections? Did you get the new server name correct?

Comment: Ping doesn't prove firewall, try telnet or test-connection in PowerShell to prove the connectivity on the port that the server is listening on

Comment: Yes to both. Test_connection to the new server's ip returned data, and the new server allows remote connections

Comment: would the server holding the database need to be configured or have an option added somewhere to allow the new server connection to pass?

Comment: Can you connect to the new server with, say, SSMS or sqlcmd from the same workstation Powershell scrip is being run?

Comment: That's the question vonPryz. The database server is the same. The powershell was running from the "old" server. The new server that connects to the same data server is the one with the issue

Answer (score 0):

In this instance:
TCP/IP needs to be enabled on both servers.
On the new server, running the command:
 `Telnet TargetServerIP 1433` 
returns a connection error from the new server. It turns out the Network Firewall is the culprit here. It doesn't have some options configured, TCP/IP being one of them. Unfortuneately, the solution here is to get our network team to enable, or Re IP the servers.